# Compilation errors with OpenCV GOLD

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi2, eye-detection

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and using OpenCV 3 Gold. I have found an example here for eye detection: https://github.com/trishume/eyeLike

When compiling on the Raspberry Pi, I got a lot of errors:

```
/home/pi/opencv-3.0.0/samples/cpp/test/eyeLike-master/src/main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, const char)':
/home/pi/opencv-3.0.0/samples/cpp/test/eyeLike-master/src/main.cpp:82:37: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'frame = cvQueryFrame(capture)'
/home/pi/opencv-3.0.0/samples/cpp/test/eyeLike-master/src/main.cpp:82:37: note: candidates are:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:560:6: note: cv::Mat& cv::Mat::operator=(const cv::Mat&)
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:560:6: note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'IplImage* {aka _IplImage}' to 'const cv::Mat&'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:2878:6: note: cv::Mat& cv::Mat::operator=(const cv::MatExpr&)
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:2878:6: note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'IplImage {aka _IplImage}' to 'const cv::MatExpr&'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1102:10: note: cv::Mat& cv::Mat::operator=(const Scalar&)
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1102:10: note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'IplImage {aka _IplImage}' to 'const Scalar& {aka const cv::Scalar_<double>&}'
src/CMakeFiles/eyeLike.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/eyeLike.dir/main.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: * [src/CMakeFiles/eyeLike.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:75: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/eyeLike.dir/all' failed
make[1]: [src/CMakeFiles/eyeLike.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:72: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: * [all] Error 2`
```

I have tested the program with OpenCV 2.4.10 and it worked very well.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: @Marcel yes i have tested it with the latest version opencv 3.0.0 that is more recent than GOLD , what's problem do you have ?

Comment: Thank you I already solved the issues. I was using some "old" example code for object detection: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier - but now I am using the updated version: http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d28/tutorial_cascade_classifier.html#gsc.tab=0